# iphone add storyboard to existing application- uinavigationcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

Hello all i have created a empty application instead of creating single page application with story board. now am trying to adapt this empty application with storyboard.

I have added a story board into application and assigned as mainstoryboard in build phase.

But when i am lauching the application my storyboard is not displaying rootviewcontroller.

it says like

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Here check my app delegate code.

> ```
> UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
> RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[rootNavigationController topViewController];
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do with the code? 
If you want to show your navigation controller on the app launch .
Go to the storyboard and tap on the NavigationController , go to attributes inspector and checkmark is Initial View Controller and also add a rootViewController to your MainNavigationController. 
Now launch app ..
Make sure you have set storyboard name in build phase?

Comment: thanks for quick response. I have done all the thing which u have mentioned here but still i can't see my rootviewcontroller

Comment: log this NSLog(@"controller is %@",self.window.rootViewController) ; show me the result...

Comment: Sorry it all my mistake i did assigned mainstoryboard in project summary thats the problem. anyways thanks all/